# Stylesheet not loading. URL duplicating on click

Tags: php, css

I have a big prob. We have a site that was working just fine but I was doing some fine tuning and somewhere along the line i messed things up. possibly in the .htaccess file.

My problem is that my css style sheet doesn't load nor do my images. ahh! They are all there.

I emptied my .htaccess file and deleted my robots.txt just to eliminate any blocking but that didn't fix it.

I validated my css file with The W3C CSS Validation Service and it said:

file not found: http://easybuildingproducts.ca/www.easybuildingproducts.ca/style.css

I feel like it has something to do with the fact that the URL is duplicated. It does that now when i click a link to any of my pages. It should be either or not both those links together. Is it possible a google cached my .htaccess or robots.txt when there was a potential redirect error? Is there a loop happening somewhere?

I was in the midst of making a custom 404 error page when this all went down.

www.easybuildingproducts.ca

Comment: Show the webpage ? http://www.easybuildingproducts.ca/style.css exists ok

Comment: It looks like all your images and styles are missing a / in front.

Answer (score 4):

Easy fix

```
<link href="www.easybuildingproducts.castyles/inside.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

That needs to be either one of the following

```
<link href="/styles/inside.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

or

```
<link href="http://www.easybuildingproducts.ca/styles/inside.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I looked at the actual website source to find this example. there are quite a lot like it

Comment: or `//www.easybuildingproducts.ca/styles/inside.css`

Answer (score 0):

Change the href to "/style.css" instead of writing your full domain out. Do the same kind of thing for all other resources that failed to load, too.

This will fix your problem, and it will also make your markup compatible if you decide to migrate to a different dsomain name in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your resources aren't being loaded (css, js, jquery, etc). Take a look at the screenshot taken from my Chrome Dev Tools > Sources tab:

[image: Missing resources]

This is because of your resources' file paths. It is definitely not a good idea to reference all of your resources with "www." in the file path.

Change

```
<link href="www.easybuildingproducts.castyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

into

```
<link href="/castyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```